# Creating and referencing an object made with different class (type Gtk.Overlay) within window class (Gtk.Window) causes runtime error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, gtk, gnome

This is the code:

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MyAnime(Gtk.Label):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")
        self.label = MyAnime()
        self.add(self.label)


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

This is the error that pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fixing.py", line 19, in <module>
    win = MyWindow()
  File "fixing.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.add(self.overlay)
RuntimeError: object at 0x7f055a193c80 of type MyAnime is not initialized
```

Of course in this example I could just create a Gtk.Label within MyWindow. But for my actual code, I am trying to create an object based on a class of type Gtk.Overlay from within the MyWindow class.

I'm confused as (to my understanding) the object is already initilized in `self.label = MyAnime()` but the runtime error says otherwise (I feel as though I am missing something very obvious :/)

EDIT: Progmatico's solution of replacing pass with `super().__init__()` worked although from looking at the runtime error and some source code from the GNOME files app, I found you can also use `Gtk.Label.__init__(self)`

Comment: Try calling `super().__init__()`, instead of `pass`.

Comment: @progmatico That worked. Thanks for the tip. I saw something like that on a page but didn't think it was relevant. Although I have another fix that I found from some gtk apps source code that I will now put in the main post along with yours :)

Comment: The main difference is that using `super`does not mention the parent class name. This is useful when subclassing. Super also solves a tricky (the diamond) problem if you use multiple inheritance. Beaware also that many times `*args`and `**kwargs` should be passed "upwards" in these calls, although it looks to be not needed in this case.

Comment: You can also move your edit to an answer for your own question (you can create that) , maybe with some more detail or helpful links about the issues involved and accept it.